# Linphone.dll not found with windows form

Tags: c#, windows-forms-designer, linphone-sdk

I want to create a g application with C# and Windows Forms. For this I have downloaded and installed the latest nuget from the official website (https://download.linphone.org/releases/windows/sdk/). But now when I want to make a call, the programme crashes with the error:

> DllNotFoundException:linphone.dll

I have now tried various things: modify LinphoneWrapper.cs, integrating dll file into the project, dll file in bin folder, ... but had no success.

I tried the same thing with C# UWP and it worked without any problems. But UWP does not look like the right way to me.

I am still inexperienced: Is it even possible with this nuget and Windows Forms, or do I have to download and build (cmake) the linphone-sdk first?

Thanks for help.

Comment: Have you tried using the Nuget ? https://gitlab.linphone.org/BC/public/linphone-sdk/-/packages

Comment: Yes, I have used it. But unfortunately it doesn't work with the dlls from this project. I was able to solve the problem, but only after using the dlls from the linphone-windows10 project.
https://gitlab.linphone.org/BC/public/linphone-windows10

Answer (score -1):

Are you building for `x64`? `linphone` doesn't support targeting `x86` ([look here](https://gitlab.linphone.org/BC/public/linphone-windows10))

Comment: Thanks, but this is a finished app and again with UWP. The point is to integrate the linphone into my project and build an app around it.